# What's a phrase for abstract / eloquent / euphemistic prose?

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm looking for a phrase like "transcendental language", but meaning eloquent rather than other-worldly.

In particular, I want to refer to a [literary] sketch as "*_* language". This sketch is *A Gotham Reverie* by Fanny Fern, in which a prostitute is referred to [revealed as a prostitute] in very abstract terms, such as "her name was Magdalen" (I'm paraphrasing), "her own unrelenting, unforgiving sex", etc.

Comment: You will have decide upon what you think it is -- if it is not eloquent then it is something else. Until you can pin down what your image of it is, it won't be possible to find a word.

Comment: @Kris, Eloquent is more like "well written". I want to say indirect. I think "euphemistic" is the closest to what I'm looking for.

Comment: why the downvotes? Is it unacceptable to forget phrases? seriously...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider also "figurative" in addition to your euphemistic, since euphemistic implies that the words you're avoiding using are somehow taboo or unpleasant, while figurative can imply flowery language in general.

Answer (score 2):

*[Refined](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/refined)* may serve, with senses including "Showing or having good feelings or good taste.  An absence of coarseness.  Not vulgar."

Being refined often is an aspect of *[high-flown](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/high-flown)* language, that is, language "pretentiously eloquent; highly figurative" or "lofty, extravagant, refined".

If the writing or your review have elements of irony, consider terms *[arch](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/arch)*, "knowing, clever, mischievous", and *[precious](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/precious)*, "treated with too much reverence" or "contrived to be cute or charming", and synonyms of the latter including *[twee](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/twee)*, "overly quaint, dainty, cute or nice" and *[saccharine](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/saccharine)*, "sentimental or romantic to the point of ridiculousness".

Comment: Didn't know about "high-flown" -- that's great too, thanks!! (Too bad I have to choose one answer ... I thought Avner's was a little more standard.)

Answer (score 0):

Confusingly similar to *euphemistic*, there’s *euphuistic*, used to describe affectation in writing or speech.

Answer (score 0):

Poetic

Poetic language, or stating 'I'm being poetic here' or 'using a poetic turn of phrase' means, using artistic or fanciful ways of describing what is going on, often indirect and using allusions.

definition poetic
[ poh-et-ik ]SHOW IPA

See synonyms for poetic on Thesaurus.com
adjective Also po·et·i·cal.
possessing the qualities or charm of poetry:
poetic descriptions of nature.