# "Death Panels" and "Job creators": Is there a word for these?

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary

Is there a word or expression that describes phrases like "Freedom fries" or "Death panels"? I'm thinking of phrases that seem intentionally designed to either re-frame a familiar concept or to be purposely evocative. The examples I can think of are mostly (US) political: "Job creators", "Death panels", "Death tax", "Freedom fries", etc.

Comment: Noun/noun pairs?

Comment: "Weasel words" or "loaded language".

Comment: Might duplicate [What's a phrase for abstract / eloquent / euphemistic prose?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57526)

Comment: More generally, "labeling". See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propaganda#Techniques

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would call them *propaganda phrases* and, in some cases, [*dog-whistle phrases*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog-whistle_politics).

Comment: I don't know why you were downvoted. This strikes me as a good answer.

Comment: Hadn't heard of "dog-whistle phrases". What a great way of describing them. MetaEd's "Weasel words" suggestion in the comments was good as well.